# how to write a shell script to make an ssh connection to a machine and continue remaining script on that machine

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am writing a script where I run the script  on one server through which I create an ssh connection to another machine and want to continue the following script code on the remote machine....  Can any body tell what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to execute a command on remote host through ssh and get the output on local host, that what i understand from you question then use.

```
ssh -n <hostname/IP> 'command'
```

where -n will Redirects stdin from /dev/null

you can store the output to a variable or file as

```
var =`ssh -n <hostname/IP> 'command'`
```

or

```
ssh -n <hostname/IP> 'command' >> output.txt
```

also if you want to send multiple command use ; for command separator.

## NOTE: ssh without password should be enable from local host to remote host.

else you need to specify password explicitly.